# Android NDK and CrystaX doesn't recognize std::index_sequence

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I try to compile this code that I copied from cppreference.com

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename Func, typename Tup, std::size_t... index>
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    return func(std::get<index>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...);
}

template<typename Func, typename Tup>
decltype(auto) invoke(Func&& func, Tup&& tup)
{
    constexpr auto Size = std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tup>::type>::value;
    return invoke_helper(std::forward<Func>(func),
                         std::forward<Tup>(tup),
                         std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}

void foo(int a, const std::string& b, float c)
{
    std::cout << a << " , " << b << " , " << c << '\n';
}
```

my Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    :=test

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=../../test.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c++_static
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++14
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

my Application.mk :

```
APP_MODULES      := test
APP_OPTIM        := release
APP_ABI          := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x86
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang
APP_STL := c++_static
```

using NDK r13b, I got this errors :

```
jni/../../test.cpp:6:10: warning: 'decltype(auto)' type specifier is a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
         ^
jni/../../test.cpp:6:59: error: no type named 'index_sequence' in namespace 'std'
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
                                                     ~~~~~^
jni/../../test.cpp:6:73: error: expected ')'
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
                                                                        ^
jni/../../test.cpp:6:29: note: to match this '('
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
                            ^
jni/../../test.cpp:6:1: error: deduced return types are a C++14 extension
decltype(auto) invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
^
jni/../../test.cpp:12:10: warning: 'decltype(auto)' type specifier is a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
decltype(auto) invoke(Func&& func, Tup&& tup)
         ^
jni/../../test.cpp:12:1: error: deduced return types are a C++14 extension
decltype(auto) invoke(Func&& func, Tup&& tup)
^
jni/../../test.cpp:17:31: error: no member named 'make_index_sequence' in namespace 'std'
                         std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
                         ~~~~~^
jni/../../test.cpp:17:55: error: initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator '>'
                         std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
                                                      ^~~
jni/../../test.cpp:28:5: error: no matching function for call to 'invoke'
    invoke(foo, args);
```

I also try using crystax 10.3.2 and got identical errors. It seems that my flag -std=c++14 doesn't seems to take effect. The errors complaint about decltyp(auto), auto return value and index_sequence. All are c++ 14 features. 
Any suggestion ?
I try run ndk-build V=1 and this is the verbose output

```
F:/Library/android-ndk-r13b/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/test/__/__/test.o.d -gcc-toolchain F:/Library/android-ndk-r13b/build//../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-integrated-as -g -target armv5te-none-linux-androideabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -mthumb -Os -DNDEBUG  -IF:/Library/android-ndk-r13b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include -IF:/Library/android-ndk-r13b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../../android/support/include -IF:/Library/android-ndk-r13b/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include -Ijni -DANDROID -std=c++14 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11     -isystem F:/Library/android-ndk-r13b/build//../platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/../../test.cpp -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/test/__/__/test.o
```

I see that both -std=c++14 and -std=c++11 is specified. Maybe the -std=c++11 take precedence ? I don't where that come from though.

Comment: I have just tried this with NDK 13.1.3345770, and `-std=c++14` simply works; `std::index_sequence` and `decltype(auto)` are recognized by the **clang** compiler. Maybe some other setting overrides your `LOCAL_CFLAGS`? Try to run `ndk-build V=1` to see the actual command line passed to the compiler.

Comment: Did you use the same Android.mk and Application.mk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I just need to specify -std=c++14 in Application.mk instead in Android.mk. So now, the Android.mk is

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    :=test

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=../../test.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c++_static
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and Application.mk :

```
APP_MODULES      := test
APP_OPTIM        := release
APP_ABI          := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x86
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++14
```

Comment: as a matter of fact, you don't need `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c++_static` in **Android.mk**